# Hide all View containing By making height 0 of parent UiView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, ios6

I am making one animation and in it i Have to make height 0 of one `UIView` named "**subView**".
now that subView contain one `UIButton` and `UIImageView`.
now i make height 0 by this method on button click

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *suvView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *subButton;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgview;
}
-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.view addSubview:suvView];
    [suvView addSubview:subButton];
    [suvView addSubview:imgview];
}

-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:suvView];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [suvView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 94, 320, 0)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
@end
```

but when i make height 0 than View named "subButton" and "imgview" are look as it is.
i want to make Them hidden when subView height is 0.

i am using XCode 4.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to hide them without resizing: `[mainview setClipsToBounds:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods for doing this :-

Firstly, If you are making the suvViews height 0 then you do not need to remove it. But simply hide the imgview and the subButton like

```
-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:suvView];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [suvView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 94, 320, 0)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    subButton.hidden = YES;
    imgview.hidden = YES;
}
@end
```

Also what you can do is reduce the heights of subButton and imgview with the suvView's height like

```
-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:suvView];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [suvView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 94, 320, 0)];
    [imgview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, x, y, z];
    [subButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, x, y, z];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

where x,y,z are the coordinates of the imgview and the subButton. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before starting the animation:

```
subButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Or you could do this from the interface builder also by setting the vertical and horizontal resize for each sub view (the button and image view)

Btw you should be using the apple recommended block based animation(if you are using iOS 4.0 and above) rather than `beginAnimations:` and `commitAnimations:`.

Comment: Jonathans answer would be the easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this code for view animation

-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
    [suvView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 94, 320, 0)];
 }
  completion:nil];
}
```